# Paypal IPN verified problems

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm experiencing some problems with my paypal ipn script:

```
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }

    // post back to PayPal system to validate
    $header = '';
    $header  = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";            
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .= "Host: www.paypal.com\r\n";
    $header .= "Connection: close\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

    $fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

    if (!$fp) {
    // HTTP ERROR
    } 
    else {
        fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
        $response = '';
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
            $res = trim($res);
            if (strpos($res,'VERIFIED') !== false) {

            }
            else {
                // not verified
            }
        }
    }
```

`if (strpos($res,'VERIFIED') !== false)` is always false.
This is what `$res` returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=14400
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=14400
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
DC: slc-a-origin-www-1.paypal.com
Date: Thu, 27 Feb 2014 20:50:47 GMT
Content-Length: 8
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: cwrClyrK4LoCV1fydGbAxiNL6iG=KVmAID_U9eq9TG0lkX119TL840BG6Xau98CeIZX3jTQTx9a4uGno9gxDJGS6VrX8CoBQnj9_n7cUnfeLjb8bD_pyJvE1_XJY5j-Sl5dVIROlu-Cn3_PmfiwL1S0RB-hCOCJzLNIzLsV7H4_xyZg7u4eCzBKTZdlfRru95teI1r2A2tFCtNcYgejjmUHfHzy4nSMco604T_4OJZX_6PvoheXYKqj8tOR_hNW_s3057XoT0wbqzwWA0YI00DZRoRocUuY77_hR6THpxJ6ZnekN3nrdsh74z4XvF39eaf2kdQLGKArjel4sFCAFtmO0NkVQs7VOM_upvhbruJQdm94oOue4UWUpx2NQMUE2JWYNgrgUaBliTrzbFgWOLFidJ1bNJoopcthU5nDUFDXDka7_JSRL44rPMWS0o0kLQIZDnfTiVqhdZsnWNT6wxH4; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: cookie_check=yes; expires=Sun, 25-Feb-2024 20:50:47 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: navcmd=_notify-validate; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: navlns=0.0; expires=Sat, 27-Feb-2016 20:50:47 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: Apache=10.73.8.134.1393534247185146; path=/; expires=Sat, 20-Feb-44 20:50:47 GMT
Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DLIVE5.WEB.1%26silo_version%3D880%26app%3Dslingshot%26TIME%3D665128787; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
Set-Cookie: Apache=10.73.8.46.1393534247177026; path=/; expires=Sat, 20-Feb-44 20:50:47 GMT
Set-Cookie: AKDC=slc-a-origin-www-1.paypal.com; expires=Thu, 27-Feb-2014 21:20:47 GMT; path=/; secure
```

Answer (score 0):

A few possible things, based off a working example I'm using...

1. You might be running into serialization issues.
2. You're posting back to ssl://www.paypal.com instead of https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
3. There may be a problem with the way you're checking for verification? My example uses `strcmp()` instead of `strpos()`

   ```
   // read raw POST data to prevent serialization issues w/ $_POST
   $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
   $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
   $myPost = array();
   foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
       $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
       if (count($keyval) == 2)
           $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
   }

   // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
   $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
   foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
       if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
           $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
       } else {
           $value = urlencode($value);
       }
       $req .= "&$key=$value";
   }

   // Post IPN back to PayPal to validate the IPN data is genuine
   $paypal_url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';

   $ch = curl_init($paypal_url);
   if ($ch == false) {
       return false;
   }

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);

   // Set TCP timeout to 30 seconds
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

   // CONFIG: Please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path
   // of the certificate as shown below. Ensure the file is readable by the webserver.
   // This is mandatory for some environments.
   // $cert = __DIR__ . "./cacert.pem";
   // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cert);

   $res = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);

   // Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
   if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
       // good to go...
   }
   ```

**References:**

- https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/
- http://paypal.github.io/sdk/sample-apps/